# In the X-Files Episode "Deadalive", did Scully cure Mulder of the alien virus without the vaccine?

Tags: mythology, the-x-files

I just watched it (going through the mythology episodes).  Mulder had what Scully "strongly believed" was the alien virus.  Doggett failed to get the vaccine from Krycek so Skully treated him with "antivirals" and it worked.

Did Scully cure Mulder of the alien virus without the vaccine (that the syndicate was working on for roughly 50 years)?

*Also* : How is it that, previously, the alien virus made a scary alien grow and burst out of someone's chest cavity, but this one made Billy Miles shed his skin and then appeared normal?

Comment: This isn't a question so much as [an attempt to start a conversation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). Voted to close.

Comment: You're wrong.  It's me trying to verify if I understood it correctly.  I'm unsure if I did because my understanding is so out of line with the rest of the story.

Comment: Sean, I edited your question to make it more focused more on the points you were asking about. Please revert if you feel it lost your original meaning.

Comment: I came across this eps. Too http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Extinction what do u think?

Comment: *"a scary alien grow and burst out of someone's chest cavity"* when did this happen?

Comment: @RoyalFlush : This happened several times.  Most prominently, in the the (first) X-Files film.

Answer (score 6):

The implication is that the alien in Billy Miles chest was "born", and assumed the identity of Billy Miles with its shape-shifting talents. Any flesh from the original Billy was absorbed, or washed away into the shower drain.

Mulder likely wasn't cured, but that the virus is dormant. Unless the producers film a third movie, there's no way for us to know conclusively.

Comment: I still can’t believe they did a second one.